# Why does Linux put Marvell SATA controllers in PATA mode by default?

Tags: sata

I have a motherboard with a Marvell SATA controller. This controller is only used to drive the eSATA ports. By default Ubuntu loads the pata_marvell module to drive these ports. However, PATA does not support hot-swapping, which is a big drawback for an eSATA port. The workaround for this is to put

```
options ahci enable_marvell=1
```

in /etc/modprobe.d/marvell-ahci.conf and then rebuild the initramdisks. This causes the ports to be controlled by ahci.

Why is pata_marvell the default? Why would I want to use it instead of AHCI? And are there any possible problems with using AHCI?

Comment: which marvell controller? did you check your bios settings for ide/ahci/raid mode? which version of ubuntu were you using? how are you determining it is using pata? is this still the case with newer versions of ubuntu?

Comment: I can't remember. Yes, it was set to AHCI. 14.04 probably. By looking at dmesg. I don't know. (I no longer have this hardware, and the eSATA port never worked properly. My new computer has USB3 which seems to work slightly better.)